# how to clear focus of spinner in order to call onItemSelected method again

Tags: android, spinner

I use several fragments in my app.

On the first one I have spinner which is not in focus. I use `requestFocus()` method and as result `onItemSelected` is executed.

After execution logic on all fragments I come back to first one fragment which is in focus now. I execute `requestFocus()` but nothing happened. `onItemSelected()` is not executed.

How can I call `onItemSelected()` second time?

I tried to use `clearFocus()` before `requestFocus()` but it doen't help.

Comment: why do you want `onItemSelected` to be called? If you want to do specific things once a fragment is shown you could simply call whatever methods you need manually. (from e.g. where you call `requestFocus`). Otherwise try `spinner.setSelection(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition())`

Comment: when I select (using UI component) some element in spinner onItemSelected is executed and next fragment is shown. When I call requestFocus() spinner receive focus and onItemSelected is executed. it's like selection element by default